# Terraform - Conditional expression for a AWS role

Tags: permissions, terraform, amazon-iam

I have the following in my module to create a role:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "default" {

  name                 = var.name

  assume_role_policy   = var.assume_role_policy

  permissions_boundary = var.account_id != "" ? var.permissions_boundary : "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.default.account_id}:policy/BoundedPermissionsPolicy"

}
```

Problem - I want to be able to set the permissions boundary argument to use the account ID if present and if not specified then make use of var.permissions_boundary (`arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.default.account_id}:policy/BoundedPermissionsPolicy`).
The code above does not work when I try to use the account ID.

Comment: Any errors present?

Comment: We need to see more content: the specific error message it's giving, the variable definitions, and the data source.

Comment: with limited info and error provided, if you change:

```arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.default.account_id}```

to

```arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}``` for current user this should work.